# Launching an iOS app running in background

Tags: ios

My requirement is like:
  I have an iOS app running in **foreground** and user press the hardware home button and switch to there app and remain idle on home screen of the phone. I want after let say **30 sec** may app will automatically open without any user interaction. Mean without using any **Notification**.

Is is technically possible? If so how to implement this.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is not so much programming related as much as checking if something is possible in general.

Comment: i have tried it using URL schemes but didn’t work for me.

Comment: @SyedAliSalman using URL scheme also requires user interaction to fire that mechanism

Comment: i tried to do somthing like that, `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@“myURLScheme://”]];` in my  `applicationDidEnterBackground` method. @Azat

Answer (score 2):

No, it is impossible to do using only allowed API